# The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint (Cursor)

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, cursor, constraints

My task is to duplicate company information using the stored procedure. I have to use cursor to complete my task as an order from my tech lead. I got this error whenever I run the SP. Other tables such as person, address I have mentioned in my previous questions were solved, now what's left is only phone & phone link table which is giving me headache.

P/S:

- EntityID = 5 (Company)

Below is my code:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[DuplicateCompanyInfo]
    @Comp_CompanyId NVARCHAR(80)


AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @CompanyID NVARCHAR(30),
        @PersonID NVARCHAR(30),
        @AddressID NVARCHAR(30),
        @PhoneLinkID NVARCHAR(30),
        @PhoneID NVARCHAR(30)
            EXEC @companyId = crm_next_id 5
            EXEC @PersonId = crm_next_id 13
            EXEC @AddressId = crm_next_id 1



        -- Add Company
        INSERT INTO Company
        (
            Comp_CompanyId, Comp_PrimaryPersonId, Comp_PrimaryAddressId, Comp_Name, Comp_Type, Comp_Status, Comp_CreatedBy,
            Comp_CreatedDate, Comp_UpdatedBy, Comp_UpdatedDate, Comp_TimeStamp, Comp_SecTerr, Comp_WebSite
        )
        SELECT  @companyId, @PersonId, @AddressId, Comp_Name, Comp_Type, Comp_Status, '1',
                GETDATE(), '1', GETDATE(), GETDATE(), Comp_SecTerr, Comp_WebSite

        FROM Company
        WHERE Comp_CompanyId = @comp_companyid
        AND Comp_Deleted is null


------- Company PhoneLink (Business) Cursor -----------------------------------------
        -- Declare Variables
        DECLARE @c_PLink_LinkID NVARCHAR(30)
        DECLARE @c_PLink_PhoneId NVARCHAR(30)
        DECLARE @c_PLink_CreatedBy NVARCHAR(30)
        DECLARE @c_PLink_CreatedDate NVARCHAR(30)
        DECLARE @c_PLink_UpdatedDate NVARCHAR(30)
        DECLARE @c_PLink_TimeStamp NVARCHAR(30)
        DECLARE @c_PLink_EntityID NVARCHAR(30)
        DECLARE @c_PLink_RecordID NVARCHAR(30)
        DECLARE @c_PLink_Type NVARCHAR(30)


        --Declare Cursor
        DECLARE CompPhoneLinkCursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT PLink_LinkID, PLink_PhoneId, PLink_CreatedBy, PLink_CreatedDate, PLink_UpdatedDate, PLink_TimeStamp,
               PLink_EntityID, PLink_RecordID, PLink_Type
        FROM PhoneLink
        INNER JOIN Phone
        ON PLink_PhoneId = Phon_PhoneId
        AND PLink_RecordID = @Comp_CompanyId
        AND Plink_EntityID = '5'
        AND Plink_Type = 'Business'
        AND Phon_Deleted is null
        AND Plink_Deleted is null


        --Open Cursor & fetch 1st row into variables
        OPEN CompPhoneLinkCursor
        FETCH NEXT FROM CompPhoneLinkCursor INTO @c_PLink_LinkID, @c_PLink_PhoneId, @c_PLink_CreatedBy, @c_PLink_CreatedDate,
                                      @c_PLink_UpdatedDate, @c_PLink_TimeStamp, @c_PLink_EntityID, @c_PLink_RecordID, @c_PLink_Type


        --Fetch successful
        --Check for a new row
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN

        EXEC @PhoneLinkID = crm_next_id 10208
        EXEC @PhoneId = crm_next_id 14


            INSERT INTO PhoneLink
            (
                PLink_LinkID, PLink_PhoneId, PLink_CreatedBy, PLink_CreatedDate, PLink_UpdatedDate,
                PLink_TimeStamp, PLink_EntityID, PLink_RecordID, PLink_Type
            )
            VALUES
            (
                @PhoneLinkID, @PhoneId, '1', GETDATE(), GETDATE(),
                GETDATE(), @c_PLink_EntityID, @c_PLink_RecordID, 'Business'
            )


        --Get next available row into variables
        FETCH NEXT FROM CompPhoneLinkCursor INTO @c_PLink_LinkID, @c_PLink_PhoneID, @c_PLink_CreatedBy, @c_PLink_CreatedDate,
                                      @c_PLink_UpdatedDate, @c_PLink_TimeStamp, @c_PLink_EntityID, @c_PLink_RecordID, @c_PLink_Type

        END

        CLOSE CompPhoneLinkCursor
        DEALLOCATE CompPhoneLinkCursor



------- Company Phone (Business) Cursor ---------------------------------------------
        -- Declare Variables
        DECLARE @c_Phon_PhoneId NVARCHAR(30)
        DECLARE @c_Phon_Number NVARCHAR(30)
        DECLARE @c_Phon_CreatedBy NVARCHAR(30)
        DECLARE @c_Phon_CreatedDate NVARCHAR(30)
        DECLARE @c_Phon_UpdatedBy NVARCHAR(30)
        DECLARE @c_Phon_UpdatedDate NVARCHAR(30)
        DECLARE @c_Phon_TimeStamp NVARCHAR(30)


        --Declare Cursor
        DECLARE CompPhoneCursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT Phon_PhoneId, Phon_Number, Phon_CreatedBy, Phon_CreatedDate, Phon_UpdatedBy, Phon_UpdatedDate, Phon_TimeStamp
        FROM Phone
        INNER JOIN PhoneLink
        ON Phon_PhoneId = PLink_PhoneId
        AND PLink_RecordID = @Comp_CompanyId
        AND Plink_EntityID = '5'
        AND Plink_Type = 'Business'
        AND Phon_Deleted is null
        AND Plink_Deleted is null


        --Open Cursor & fetch 1st row into variables
        OPEN CompPhoneCursor
        FETCH NEXT FROM CompPhoneCursor INTO @c_Phon_PhoneId, @c_Phon_Number, @c_Phon_CreatedBy, @c_Phon_CreatedDate,
                                      @c_Phon_UpdatedBy, @c_Phon_UpdatedDate, @c_Phon_TimeStamp


        --Fetch successful
        --Check for a new row
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN


        INSERT INTO Phone
        (
            Phon_PhoneId, Phon_Number, Phon_CreatedBy, Phon_CreatedDate, Phon_UpdatedBy, Phon_UpdatedDate, Phon_TimeStamp
        )
        VALUES
        (
            @PhoneID, @c_Phon_Number, '1', GETDATE(), '1', GETDATE(), GETDATE()
        )


        --Get next available row into variables
        FETCH NEXT FROM CompPhoneCursor INTO @c_Phon_PhoneId, @c_Phon_Number, @c_Phon_CreatedBy, @c_Phon_CreatedDate,
                                      @c_Phon_UpdatedBy, @c_Phon_UpdatedDate, @c_Phon_TimeStamp

        END

        CLOSE CompPhoneCursor
        DEALLOCATE CompPhoneCursor



------- Company PhoneLink (Fax) Cursor ----------------------------------------------
        -- Declare Variables
        DECLARE @cf_PLink_LinkID NVARCHAR(30)
        DECLARE @cf_PLink_PhoneId NVARCHAR(30)
        DECLARE @cf_PLink_CreatedBy NVARCHAR(30)
        DECLARE @cf_PLink_CreatedDate NVARCHAR(30)
        DECLARE @cf_PLink_UpdatedDate NVARCHAR(30)
        DECLARE @cf_PLink_TimeStamp NVARCHAR(30)
        DECLARE @cf_PLink_EntityID NVARCHAR(30)
        DECLARE @cf_PLink_RecordID NVARCHAR(30)
        DECLARE @cf_PLink_Type NVARCHAR(30)


        --Declare Cursor
        DECLARE CompanyFaxLinkCursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT PLink_LinkID, PLink_PhoneId, PLink_CreatedBy, PLink_CreatedDate, PLink_UpdatedDate, PLink_TimeStamp,
               PLink_EntityID, PLink_RecordID, PLink_Type
        FROM PhoneLink
        INNER JOIN Phone
        ON PLink_PhoneId = Phon_PhoneId
        AND PLink_RecordID = @Comp_CompanyId
        AND Plink_EntityID = '5'
        AND Plink_Type = 'Fax'
        AND Plink_Deleted is null
        AND Phon_Deleted is null


        --Open Cursor & fetch 1st row into variables
        OPEN CompanyFaxLinkCursor
        FETCH NEXT FROM CompanyFaxLinkCursor INTO @cf_PLink_LinkID, @cf_PLink_PhoneId, @cf_PLink_CreatedBy, @cf_PLink_CreatedDate,
                                      @cf_PLink_UpdatedDate, @cf_PLink_TimeStamp, @cf_PLink_EntityID, @cf_PLink_RecordID, @cf_PLink_Type


        --Fetch successful
        --Check for a new row
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN

        EXEC @PhoneLinkID = crm_next_id 10208
        EXEC @PhoneId = crm_next_id 14


            INSERT INTO PhoneLink
            (
                PLink_LinkID, PLink_PhoneId, PLink_CreatedBy, PLink_CreatedDate, PLink_UpdatedDate,
                PLink_TimeStamp, PLink_EntityID, PLink_RecordID, PLink_Type
            )
            VALUES
            (
                @PhoneLinkID, @PhoneId, '1', GETDATE(), GETDATE(),
                GETDATE(), @cf_PLink_EntityID, @cf_PLink_RecordID, 'Fax'
            )           


        --Get next available row into variables
        FETCH NEXT FROM CompanyFaxLinkCursor INTO @cf_PLink_LinkID, @cf_PLink_PhoneID, @cf_PLink_CreatedBy, @cf_PLink_CreatedDate,
                                      @cf_PLink_UpdatedDate, @cf_PLink_TimeStamp, @cf_PLink_EntityID, @cf_PLink_RecordID, @cf_PLink_Type

        END

        CLOSE CompanyFaxLinkCursor
        DEALLOCATE CompanyFaxLinkCursor



------- Company Phone (Fax) Cursor --------------------------------------------------
        -- Declare Variables
        DECLARE @cf_Phon_PhoneId NVARCHAR(30)
        DECLARE @cf_Phon_Number NVARCHAR(30)
        DECLARE @cf_Phon_CreatedBy NVARCHAR(30)
        DECLARE @cf_Phon_CreatedDate NVARCHAR(30)
        DECLARE @cf_Phon_UpdatedBy NVARCHAR(30)
        DECLARE @cf_Phon_UpdatedDate NVARCHAR(30)
        DECLARE @cf_Phon_TimeStamp NVARCHAR(30)


        --Declare Cursor
        DECLARE CompanyFaxCursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT Phon_PhoneId, Phon_Number, Phon_CreatedBy, Phon_CreatedDate, Phon_UpdatedBy, Phon_UpdatedDate, Phon_TimeStamp
        FROM Phone
        INNER JOIN PhoneLink
        ON Phon_PhoneId = PLink_PhoneId
        AND PLink_RecordID = @Comp_CompanyId
        AND Plink_EntityID = '5'
        AND Plink_Type = 'Fax'
        AND Plink_Deleted is null
        AND Phon_Deleted is null


        --Open Cursor & fetch 1st row into variables
        OPEN CompanyFaxCursor
        FETCH NEXT FROM CompanyFaxCursor INTO @cf_Phon_PhoneId, @cf_Phon_Number, @cf_Phon_CreatedBy, @cf_Phon_CreatedDate,
                                      @cf_Phon_UpdatedBy, @cf_Phon_UpdatedDate, @cf_Phon_TimeStamp


        --Fetch successful
        --Check for a new row
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN


        INSERT INTO Phone
        (
            Phon_PhoneId, Phon_Number, Phon_CreatedBy, Phon_CreatedDate, Phon_UpdatedBy, Phon_UpdatedDate, Phon_TimeStamp
        )
        VALUES
        (
            @PhoneID, @cf_Phon_Number, '1', GETDATE(), '1', GETDATE(), GETDATE()
        )


        --Get next available row into variables
        FETCH NEXT FROM CompanyFaxCursor INTO @cf_Phon_PhoneId, @cf_Phon_Number, @cf_Phon_CreatedBy, @cf_Phon_CreatedDate,
                                      @cf_Phon_UpdatedBy, @cf_Phon_UpdatedDate, @cf_Phon_TimeStamp

        END

        CLOSE CompanyFaxCursor
        DEALLOCATE CompanyFaxCursor
```

My table structure is as below:

Phone Link Table:

```
PLink_LinkID | PLink_EntityID | PLink_RecordID | PLink_Type | PLink_PhoneID
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
1            | 5              | 2              | Business   | 1
2            | 5              | 3              | Fax        | 2
3            | 5              | 2              | Fax        | 3
4            | 5              | 3              | Business   | 4
```

Phone Table:

```
 Phon_PhoneID | Phon_Number
 --------------------------
 1            | 11111111
 2            | 22222222
 3            | 33333333
 4            | 44444444
```

Now whenever I execute this stored procedure I will get the error shown below. I've tried swapping every `Phone` table with its `PhoneLink` table in order to insert phone first only link to company, but I still got the following error repeated twice:

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Procedure DuplicateCompanyInfo, Line 150 (Assumed)
>
> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_PhoneLink_PhoneId". The conflict occurred in database "CRM", table "dbo.Phone", column 'Phon_PhoneId'.
>
> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Procedure DuplicateCompanyInfo, Line 160 (Assumed)
>
> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_PhoneLink_PhoneId". The conflict occurred in database "CRM", table "dbo.Phone", column 'Phon_PhoneId'.

I know it's a very straight forward error message but I can't fix it. I'm new in SQL. Please help!

Comment: Please read how to create a [mcve]. You posted a lot of code, please focus on only the code that's relevant to the question.

Comment: Sorry sir, I have edited and shorten it by removing `Person_Phone` and only leave `Company Phone`, is it okay?

Comment: I'm not asking you for me, I'm asking you for you. Your question will have a better chance of getting faster and more accurate answers the shorter and clearer it is. I, for example, usually don't even bother to read through questions that are as long as yours, and I'm sure I'm not the only one. Remember we are all here on our spare time, no one is getting paid to answer questions in stackoverflow. Help us to help you by keeping your questions as short, focused, and readable as possible.

Comment: Understand, I'm new here so didn't know much about it. Now that you've mentioned I'm more clear about it, thanks for guiding me. Will keep that in mind for my future questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view all the constraints by this command:

```
exec sp_helpconstraint 'mytable'
```

Seems like there are duplicates.

Comment: I have checked for `PhoneLink` table, it does have a constraint of foreign key, constraint name `FK_PhoneLink_PhoneID`, status_enable as "enabled", status_for_replication as "Is_For_Replication", constraint_keys as `PLink_PhoneID` and REFERENCES CRM.dbo.Phone(Phon_PhoneId). The problem is I don't know how to fix this constraint problem. I'm new to SQL, may ask questions that are easy to be solved, apologies for that.

Comment: I've upvoted & accepted your answer as I believe you've helped me cleared some confusion, but still hope you can guide me on fixing the constraint problem. Thanks

Comment: I've solved it by changing all the `@c_PLink_EntityID, @c_PLink_RecordID` in `VALUES` to `'5',@companyid` and it worked perfectly now. Thanks anyway!